# Split line in three words and then rearrange it to create a php array

Tags: regex, split, notepad++, delimiter

I have these lines:

```
 FOO    100     BOR  
 PAL    350     PIL  
 KIL    090     KUP
 FAS    130     FOO's BAR
 FAO    120     Pizza's joy poy
```

and I need to transform them as following

```
 array(100, "FOO", "BOR"),
 array(350, "PAL", "PIL"),
 array(090, "KIL", "KUP"),
 array(130, "FAS", "FOO's BAR"),
 array(120, "FAO", "Pizza's joy poy"),
```

(the words delimiter is a tab)
so far this expression was working fine but it works only two words (not three):

```
Find : (^.*)    (.*?$)
Replace: array\("\2", \1\)\,
```

What about these?

```
 125    My Pot    FAO
 120    Pizza's joy poy  POI
```

to

```
array("My Pot", 125, "FAO"),
array("Pizza's joy poy", 120, "POI"),
```

Is it possible with notepad++ or another editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

Find: `(?m)^[^\S\r\n]*(\S+)[ \t]+(\S+)[ \t]+(\S+)`
Replace: `array($2, "$1", "$3"),`

https://regex101.com/r/xZjcCO/1

---

If you have this

> FOO    100     BOR
>    PAL    350     PIL
>    KIL    090     KUP
>    FAS    130     FOO's BAR
>    FAO    120     Pizza's joy poy

change the regex to this `(?m)^[^\S\r\n]*(\S+)[ \t]+(\S+)[ \t]+(\S+(?:[^\S\r\n]*\S+)*)`

which trims the whitespace at the end.

https://regex101.com/r/3d5JTh/1

output :

```
array(100, "FOO", "BOR"),  
array(350, "PAL", "PIL"),  
array(090, "KIL", "KUP"),
array(130, "FAS", "FOO's BAR"),
array(120, "FAO", "Pizza's joy poy"),
```

---

**update**

You can mix phrases as long as there is a tab maintained delimiter :

`(?m)^[^\S\r\n]*(\S+(?:[^\S\t\r\n]*\S+)*)\t+(\S+(?:[^\S\t\r\n]*\S+)*)\t+(\S+(?:[^\S\t\r\n]*\S+)*)`

https://regex101.com/r/CoiGtU/1

Output

```
array(100, "FOO", "BOR"),  
array(350, "PAL", "PIL"),  
array(090, "KIL", "KUP"),
array(130, "FAS", "FOO's BAR"),
array(120, "FAO", "Pizza's joy poy"),

array(My Pot, "125", "FAO"),
array(Pizza's joy poy, "120", "POI"),
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but you've forgotten to escape the "(" & ")" so it would be like: array\\($2, "$1", "$3"\\),

Comment: @Hexer10 - I think on the replacement side, metachars (except \ ) don't need to be escaped.

Comment: Yah on the replace one, another thing, is there any way to make as delimiter only the tab and not the spaces?

Comment: @Hexer10 - Yeah, just remove the space in the class, or just change it to `\t+`. I put in a space because, there was no tab in your sample.

Comment: I've tried this `(?m)^[^\S\r\n]*(\S+)[\t+]+(\S+)[\t+]+(\S+)` but it doens't work properly with all lines, I'm going to update the post, with more examples

Comment: @Hexer10 - I added an update which does the last field, and trims whitespace.. Out of curiosity though, why un-accept this answer ?

Comment: I've accepted it, I've add two more examples(to the end of the post) that I need to solve and then I'm done

Comment: Isn't that just switching the "parts" of the expressions?   Sorry I'm a rookie in this argoment

Comment: @Hexer10 - Yeah, that can be done, as long as the delimiter is a _tab_. I'll try to get that. But, it will be more complex.

Comment: Yeah, the delimiter is always a _tab_

Comment: @Hexer10 - Ok, put it up for you .. The only difference now is the quotes are not around what _was_ the number field. This can be distinguished using an even more complex regex, with a conditional replacement. Let me know if you need that. What version of NP++ are you using ?

Comment: It works perfectly! The Replace With is: `array\("$2", $1, "$3"\),`

Comment: @Hexer10 - Oh, you must have the NP version where it does process conditionals, that's why it needs to escape the `()`. Well, there is that quote part, let me know if you need that resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You could search for:

```
^\h*(?>(\d+)|(\S[\S ]*))\t+(?>(\d+)|(\S[\S ]*))\t+(.*?)\h*$
```

This ensures integer fields doesn't have quotes around them.

and replace with:

```
array\((?1"\4":\3), (?3"\2":\1), "\5"\),
```

In action:

[image]

Comment: You don't need `m` flag too in Notepad++.

Comment: Not sure you need the atomic or assertion groups.

Comment: @sln Thank you. I often use atomic groups in replace of nc groups. Removed lookaheads.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

[`^\s*([A-Z]+)[\t\s]+(\d+)[\s\t]+(\w+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/ZLGwid/1)

with substitution:

```
array(\2, "\1", "\3"),
```

Output:

```
array(100, "FOO", "BOR"),
array(350, "PAL", "PIL"),
array(090, "KIL", "KUP"),
```